# No tick call when using phonegap + hammerjs + angularjs or zonejs + android

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, phonegap-build, hammer.js

I have an app built in angular2 that works fine in browser and when phonegap-bundled for iOS. It uses hammerjs to handle touch events like pan and pinch.

However, when I bundle it for Android, things go haywire.

*update: isolated case on github: https://github.com/daedeloth/phonegap-hammer-zone-angular-issue *

After some debugging I managed to isolate the problem to "tick" not being called as often as it should. On iOS and in browser (any browser really, even IE), during any drag action the tick method is called on even the slightest move. When bundled for android, it is only called at the end of the drag, and even then not always.

I've added a console.log in core.umd.js to monitor the tick method calls, so I'm pretty sure the problem originates here.

Anyone else noticed similar behaviour?

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: will need to do loads of isolation then :/

Comment: Do you have fastclick.js included? I had the same issue and it was because of it.

Comment: Uploaded code at https://github.com/daedeloth/phonegap-hammer-zone-angular-issue